# Is there something wrong with my usage of AJAX here?

Tags: html, ajax, request

I am trying to test out some simple ajax (without using jquery) to have a button click display the text of a text file called "Knuckles Theme.txt". I know that my files are all in the right place because I also added a link to the text file on my html page, and when I run the html in the browser, the link takes me to the text file as it should. However, when I click on the button that is supposed to use the ajax, nothing happens. Specifically, the readyState of my request will be 4, but the status always comes out as 0. Why? Am I doing something wrong here?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="show">
<br>
<br>
<label id="song"></label>
<label id="error"></label>
<br>
<a href="./ajaxFolder/Knuckles Theme.txt" alt="Nope">Knock Knock It's Knuckles!</a>

<script>
function show() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("song").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = this.readyState + " " + this.status;
    }   
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "./ajaxFolder/Knuckles Theme.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Status 0 indicates a network or security error. The developer tools console should have more information.

Comment: The `<label>` element holds the label for a form control like an `<input>`, it isn't a generic element to assign arbitrary data to.

Comment: The `alt` attribute holds text to present if an image can't be displayed. Putting it on an `<a>` element is nonsense.

Comment: `<br>` isn't supposed to be used as a substitute for CSS margin or padding.

Comment: Try using `Knuckles+Theme` or `Knuckles%20Theme` instead of a space. Some servers are sensitive about that.

Comment: Also, if you're opening the file using a `file://` URL, ajax isn't going to work without a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

If the target URL exists then it will work, as you can see below:

```js
function show() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += this.readyState + " " + this.status+"<br>";
if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("song").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="show">
<br>
<br>
<label id="song"></label>
<hr>Ajax log:<br>
<label id="error"></label>
<br>
<a href="./ajaxFolder/Knuckles Theme.txt">Knock Knock It's Knuckles!</a>
```

I replaced your URL with a publicly available one and it works.